# Forms Authentication — Where are roles stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Where are the roles below stored?

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "customer");    
Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "admin");
```

If I add a user to a role using the code then the membership persists. I cant see a built in database in my project and I have not manually specified a database. Am I going mad?

Comment: are you working with AD Roles or are you looking at custom role security?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>

Comment: Ok, can  you give more code please so that I can look at your entire implementation

Comment: open the web.config and see the connection string. Try to connect to the database server specified in that.

Comment: if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
{
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
}

Comment: Depends on how you rmembership is configured. Check your web.config.

Comment: Have you checked connection string in your web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Information about role storage may be picked from web.config
This db might have been created for you by asp.net itself, and is called

```
aspnetdb
```

Please look at this as well:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sir, you are a god damn star!!!!!!! The mdf file wasn't showing and hadn't been included in the database so I just had to "Show All Files" and it showed.

Comment: Database location App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF